# How to convert xml string to list of java objects using jaxb having different root and child element

Tags: java, jaxb

I have below mentioned xml string and Team class. I want to convert all the row element to list of team using jaxb.

```
<team-all>
 <query-output>
    <row teamId="1" teamName ="MyTeam1" />
    <row teamId="2" teamName ="MyTeam2" />
 </query-output>
</team-all>

public class Team {

private String teamId;
private String teamName;

public String getTeamId() {
    return teamId;
}

public void setTeamId(String teamId) {
    this.teamId = teamId;
}

public String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="team-all")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AllTeam{

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="query-output")
    @XmlElement(name="row")
    private List<Team> teams;

    //getters and setters

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Team {

@XmlAttribute
private String teamId;
@XmlAttribute
private String teamName;

public String getTeamId() {
    return teamId;
}

public void setTeamId(String teamId) {
    this.teamId = teamId;
}

public String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
}
}
```

Then

```
Unmarshaller um = JAXBContext.newInstance(AllTeam.class).createUnmarshaller();
AllTeam tm = um.unmarshall(new File("pathToXml"));
```

The unmarshall method can accept different inputs, if the file doesn't suits you.